# Generation model using Forge (Design Automation) makes elements invisible

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I have some troubles after Forge model generation. The main goal is to get rvt model from JSON.
I have tested my code with Revit API in Revit. It works nice. But when add bundle to the Forge app and got rvt result - I have faced with weird glitch. I can`t see any wall in the project, but walls exist. I have checked with lookupRevit and saw walls and ids.
The question is "How to make invisible walls be visible?"
I have attached the recording demonstrating my glitch.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WiZC2VLcVSc

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for escalating this issue here from the original thread in the Revit API discussion forum on [Generation model using Forge (Design Automation) makes elements invisible](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/generation-model-using-forge-design-automation-makes-elements/m-p/10179538)!

Answer (score 1):

Please share the code for a minimal reproducible case so we can take a look. I am not aware of any way to achieve this result just creating a wall and saving the BIM. So, it will be interesting to see how you succeed with this feat.

Correction: a colleague spotted the problem in your video:

**It looks like the walls were created in Phase 3, and the view phase is 1.**

Copy-pasting them puts them on the active phase thus making them visible. (At least best I can tell from the video!)

[image: Invisible wall phase]

Comment: Thanks. You solved it. Problem was in phase, but this is weird why third phase was used. I will check it. Thanks again!